# Mips Instruction Format(machine code)

Tags: mips, offset

Mips Instruction Format :

00010110001100101111111111111110

In this case the instruction is located at address 0x80000014

It's and BNE instruction with Operands : Rs = $s2 and Rt = $s1, with an offset of -2
I know it's possible to solve this question via this formulae : *Pc+4-offset* 
which in this case would yield 0x80000010. However is it because the PC is always assumed to be an instruction ahead(4bytes) hence *Pc+4* and the offset is *-2x8* so Pc+4-8 gives me 0x80000010. Can some kind soul explain step by step what am I supposed to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MIPS branch offset is *a signed displacement (expressed in number of instructions) from the instruction following the branch*.

In other words, in your case with MIPS32, the following instruction is at 0x800000018. The offset -2 is multiplied with the instruction size 4, giving -0x8.

The instruction branched to is in other words `0x80000018-0x8 = 0x80000010`.